# How to create Class Diagram in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, class, uml

I just wanted to create the class diagram of my project in Eclipse.The project is already implemented,suggest me any tool that sketch the Diagram of this project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Model Development Tools (MDT)](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2).

For reverse engineering, you can use [JUPE](http://jupe.binaervarianz.de/).

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectAid` generates classes diagram when you are simply drag and dropping classes from Project manager to the diagram.

`UMLGraph` creates class/activities diagrams automatically from the code and append them to javadocs.

As far as I know, both work for Java. I don't know if they support other languages.

`Papyrus` is the very powerful tool for hand creation of any UML and other diagrams